# How to get rotating and/or rotfloat to work

Tags: floats, rotating

Using LyX 1.6.5/MacTex-2009 my floating sideways figures only occupy half the page and the other half of the figure disappears off the left margin. I tried the rotfloat and rotating packages and they both give the same result.

The environment begins with `\begin{sidewaysfigure}`.  The text is properly rotated but it just never gets past the half-way point of the page (along the short dimension in portrait).

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This example is compilable and works as expected:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight]{Test}
\caption{Test example}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps do it like this or post some concrete code.

Answer (score 2):

You might also try `isorot` package, which worked for me better than `rotating` or `pdflscape`.